# Unreal Engine 5 Pixel Streaming

Tags: powershell, websocket, webrtc, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Did any one tried Pixel streaming in Unreal Engine 5, if tried please tell me how you have done or any tutorial to follow.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/getting-started-with-pixel-streaming-in-unreal-engine/

Acc to this docs

I don't know how to run this in powershell
SignallingWebServer\platform_scripts\cmd\setup.ps1
SignallingWebServer\platform_scripts\cmd\Start_SignallingServer.ps1

MyPixelStreamingApplication.exe -PixelStreamingIP=127.0.0.1 -PixelStreamingPort=8888

anyone know powershell and pixelstreaming

I'm stuck on this problem very long time

why negative marking, if its stupid question please answer me.... just tell me how to run those commands in powershell

```
                                                              I'm not asking how to do the whole project !!
```

Comment: why negative marking, if its stupid question please answer me.... just tell me how to run those commands in powershell                                                                   I'm not asking how to do the whole project !!

Comment: See [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far?

Negs would be because you're asking a poor question, and asking for information related to fundamental usage of PowerShell that could be found through a Google search. Search for "Run PowerShell as Admin", "Changing directory in PowerShell" and "How to run a ps1 file in PowerShell". For more specific errors with the setup file being run, please follow the guidelines in the "asking a question" article and post a new question, or view the help articles you've linked and see what may have failed

Answer (score 0):

```
Start-Process -FilePath SignallingWebServer\platform_scripts\cmd\setup.ps1
```